# Не отображается панель

Tags: bootstrap

При нажатии на 'читать далее>>' просто закрывается панель с новостью, а новая не открывается. Вот код:

```
 <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane active">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <p class="bord3"></p>
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-12">
                                    <p class="header_style">НОВОСТИ</p>
                                    <p class="news_header">Семинар "периоды" 1 апреля 2016.</p>
                                    <p class="news_body">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled....</p>
                                    <p class="news_link">
                                        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel2">читать дальше>></a>
                                    </p>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <p class="block_element_3"></p>
                        <p class="bord3"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <div id="panel2" class="tab-pane">
                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-11 col-lg-11">
                                    <p class="bord3"></p>
                                    <div class="container-fluid">
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-xs-5">
                                                123124123
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Вот скрипт открытия табов:

```
$('[data-toggle=tab]').click(function () {
    var tab = this.hash;

    $('.tab-pane.active').fadeOut('fast')
            .add('.active').add($(this).parent()).toggleClass('active')
            .delay(500).promise().then(function () {
        $(tab).addClass('active').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас #panel2, которую вы активируете, находится внутри панели #panel1, которую вы дезактивируете.